# How can we perform specific actions on only the first Opportunity of an Account ,rest of the opportunities will be treated differently?

Tags: opportunity, process-builder, account, relationships

I have a requirement where I am supposed to perform a certain action on only the first opportunity of an Account,subsequent Opps being treated differently.
What I've done is created a checkbox on Account(read only and default unchecked),and using a process builder on Opportunity which checks for the checkbox value.

If checkbox is false, then it performs specific actions and updates the checkbox on Account.

Next time when an opportunity is created ,it checks for the checkbox value,and performs action only when it is true,otherwise performs some different actions.

But my requirement is tricky :

Account------>Opportunity------>Quote----->(m-d)Custom obj

I want to create 2 records of Custom object for the very first Opportunity of an Account, but only 1 record for subsequent Opportunities of an Account.

I can't write code for the same as I am working on Professional Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have an intermediate child object between your opportunity and the custom object you need to create that object as well and store its ID before you go for creation of the custom object.

We can create related records in process builder but cannot store the created record's ID for upcoming actions and the actions are independent.

I have implemented your requirement with use of **process builder** in conjunction with **visual flows**.

The custom object name is **Delivery**.

I call the flow every time the opportunity is created and perform the business logic in the flow.

[image: Process Builder]

[image: Visual Flow]

I have tested the same and works as expected.

Please let me know if you have any question with the approach.

Comment: Unfortunately Visual Workflow is not available in Professional Edition so this won't fix the problem. https://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

Comment: Okay then you can fix this problem by creating two process builder. One on Opportunity and another on Quote. From Opportunity create a quote and mark a checkbox as identifier that it is being created from process builder and upon such quote creation create delivery(Custom Object) records required (1 or 2) depending on the Account's checkbox which you created. Let me know, I'll post the details as a new answer if you are unable to get it right..